# perl how to use pack\unpack

Tags: perl, pack

I want to put in variable one byte in binary represantation of '\x01' value.

How can I do it in perl (I guess I should use pack procedure)

Comment: You need to clarify if you need some string representation of a value or the value itself. `0x01`, `1`, `001` and `0b00000001` are all the same value.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need `pack` for that.

```
print "\x01";
```

Comment: I don't want to print this value. I want to send it as a post data in request. So I need to put it as a first byte.

Comment: Then put it as the first byte.  Just don’t use something that’s too big to fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
my $x = 1;
my $y = 0x01;
my $z = hex '01';

print chr for $x, $y, $z;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t | xxd
0000000: 0101 01                                  ...
```

Or,

```
printf '%02X' for $x, $y, $z;
```

depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

pack("C", "\x01");

Comment: Am I right that  "C  An unsigned char (octet) value" but I need a hexadecimal value

Comment: printf("%02X", pack("C", "\x01"));

Answer (score -2):

Thank you. I've already sorted it out.

What I was need is

```
my $post = pack("H1", '\x01');
```

Comment: HUH? You need it in the high nybble?  That makes no sense.  You're just doing a `<<4` operation, for small enough values like `\x01`: `printf "%#b\n", pack("H", "\x01")` yeilds `0b10000`.